# ocultar divs y mostrar un div diferente cuando se hayan ocultado todos (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cuando doy click en estos divs se ocultan, Quiero lograr que cuando un usuario oculte todos los divs se active un div con un mensaje, pero solo cuando acabe de ocultarlos todos.

```
<div class='open'>Ocultar 1</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 2</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 3</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 4</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 5</div>

/* DIV A MOSTRAR */
<div class='oculto'>-CONTENIDO MENSAJE-</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".open").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        if (!comprobar_visibles('.open')) {
            $('.oculto').show();
        }
    });
});

function comprobar_visibles(elemento) {
    if ($(elemento).is(':visible')) {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.oculto {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 1</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 2</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 3</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 4</div>
<div class='open'>Ocultar 5</div>

/* DIV A MOSTRAR */
<div class='oculto'>-CONTENIDO MENSAJE-</div>
```

He creado un método que mediante la función `is()` comprueba si existe algún elemento de la clase `.open` visible. Si existe alguno devuelve `true` si no existe devuelve `false`. Al hacer un `click` en cada uno de los elementos a ocultar compruebo que si tras ocultarse ese siguen existiendo elementos visibles. De no haberlos es cuando muestro el `<div>` con la clase `.oculto`.